# Redact information in a pdf using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to redact some information in a pdf file using Python. Is there a library available to do it ? I have tried 'PyPDF2' and 'Reportlab' but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

fin = open('source.pdf', 'rb')
reader = PdfFileReader(fin)
writer = PdfFileWriter()
```

Or consult a site like either of the following:
https://www.binpress.com/manipulate-pdf-python/

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/06/06/creating-and-manipulating-pdfs-with-pdfrw/

Let me know if that helps, given your question is more of a open-ended question.